# Replace text with multiple boxes

Tags: jquery

I'm starting with jQuery and I need this is a project.

For example I have this:

```
<ul id="grid">
  <li class="box1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!</li>
  <li class="box2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!</li>
  <li class="box3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!</li>
</ul>
```

And Information for the grid items

```
<div class="box_info_1">Info for grid item</div>
<div class="box_info_2">Info for grid item</div>
<div class="box_info_3">Info for grid item</div>
```

And a div:

```
<div id="promo">I want to set grid info here</div>
```

What i want to accomplish is when I hover over a box, the promo div replaces the content with the corresponding info_box

So when I hover over box1, i want the content of box_info_1 in the promo div

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love to use data element selectors, and so can you!

Data elements are part of the HTML5 standard, [seen here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes), allowing a user to associate ad-hoc data with any element.  They are available in [all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=dataset).  Further, jQuery defines a simple standard to read and write to data attributes through the [$.data() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).  The following example stores a CSS-selector in a data-element for each element, and then references it when implementing the hover handler.

First, tell each "box" which box-info element it is assigned to (we'll use a CSS-selector in a data attribute), as follow:

```
 <ul id="grid">
   <li class="box box1" data-item=".box_info_1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!</li>
   <li class="box box2" data-item=".box_info_2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!</li>
   <li class="box box3" data-item=".box_info_3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!</li>
 </ul>
```

Then use the following JavaScript to get the element and replace the contents of promo:

```
 $('.box').hover(function() {
   $('#promo').text($($(this).data('item')).text());
 });
```

Comment: Is `data-item` part of an official standard? If so, can you provide a link? It looks very nice to me!

Comment: Yes, it's part of the data-* element functionality of HTML5.  See edits (2nd paragraph) of my answer for a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.box1').hover(function(){
    $('#promo').text($('.box_info_1').text());
});
```

Or, for all the boxes

```
$('#grid li').hover(function(){
    var currentNumber = $(this).attr('class').substr(3);
    var currentText = $('.box_info_'+currentNumber).text();
    $('#promo').text(currentText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = $('#promo').text();
$('#grid li').hover(function() {
    var boxIndex = $('#grid li').index(this);
    $('#promo').empty().text($('.box_info_' + (boxIndex + 1) + '').text());
},
function() {
    $('#promo').empty().text(txt);
});
```

Comment: @user868376 this will set `#promo` text in `hover` and for hover out it will set the default text